# "Invalid command line parameters" error when running package from job

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I'm having an issue scheduling a .dtsx package to execute as a SQL Server Agent job. I've Googled the problem, but can't find the required solution for my particular issue.

The SQL Server version is 2012 Business Intelligence Edition.

The package runs fine within Visual Studio.

The job is set to run under the "SQL Server Agent Service Account".

The file is on the same server as the DB.

The error log in part is:

> ...complete  End Progress  Progress: 2013-01-09 20:51:48.58
>   Source: Inheader File Import      Validating: 33% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2013-01-09 20:51:48.58     Source: Inheader File
>   Import      Validating: 66% complete  End Progress  Progress:
>   2013-01-09 20:51:48.59     Source: Inheader File Import
>   Validating: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2013-01-09
>   20:51:48.59     Source: Product File Import  ...  The command line
>   parameters are invalid...  The step failed.

This looks similar to the log generated when running the package within VS, so it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue - it looks to be processing the script.

I haven't changed the command line parameters from those generated when configuring the step, they are(I've altered sensitive data):

```
/FILE "\"C:\...filepath...\package.dtsx\""  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
```

A lot of the links I have found don't really mention the file type packages, and I'm a bit stuck so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm also confused as to why the error wouldn't occur prior to the execution of the package.

Comment: To confirm, you are running this as a SQL Agent job step of SQL Server Integration Services and not something unusual like an OS Command or TSQL hitting xp cmdshell?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is accurate:

`/FILE "\"C:\...filepath...\package.dtsx\""  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E`

then the backslash and quote before the start of the path, and the backslash and quote after the .dtsx extention, are the likely culprits.

Things should look more like this:

`/FILE "C:\...filepath...\package.dtsx"  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I changed this and I'm now getting a different issue - "integration services evaluation period has expired".  I didn't perform the initial install, but it seems that the original SQL Server only supports SSIS for evaluation.  It's now SQL Server 2012 Business intelligence edition.

The thing I'm unclear on, is why it looked like the file was processing initially - surely if the command line parameter was wrong it wouldn't have accessed the file in the first place?